# Failed making scrollable a ConstraintLayout in an Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-constraintlayout, android-scrollview

Recently I tried to create a fragment and the LinearLayout is bigger than the screen and I need to use the ScrollView. I've tried different ways reading other questions in Stackoverflow and I couldn't resolve the issue.

This is my XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.configuration.ConfigurationFragment">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_configuration_first_tittle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/configuration_first_title"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved... The scrollview was working.
I only need to add marginBotton with enough height size to considere the Botton Navigation Bar